# "The best overloaded Add method 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(System.Guid)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
List<PageInfo> subPages = new List<PageInfo>();
// ...
// some code to populate subPages here...
// ...
List<Guid> subPageGuids = new List<Guid> {from x in subPages select x.Id}; //doesn't work
```

PageInfo has an Id field which is of type Guid. So x.Id is a System.Guid.

2nd line of code above does not work...I get errors:

> The best overloaded Add method
>      'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(System.Guid)'
>      for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

And

> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>      to 'System.Guid'

I've only been coding in C# for about a week, but I've done a similar pattern before and never had this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want:

```
List<Guid> subPageGuids = new List<Guid>(from x in subPages select x.Id);
```

(note the curly braces changed to regular braces)

That will call the constructor of List that takes an IEnumerable (which is what the linq query returns) as a parameter.  Right now you're trying to use the syntax for an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! That explains why when I looked at the other times I've used this pattern it looked like I was doing the exact same thing. My eyes weren't differentiating between the curlies and the braces. I've been using Python for too long I guess.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `Add()` is called and not `AddRange()`.

You could use this syntax instead:

```
List<Guid> subPageGuids = (from x in subPages select x.id).ToList();
```

or

```
List<Guid> subPageGuids = new List<Guid>();
subPageGuids.AddRange(from x in subPages select x.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using a list initializer here incorrectly. The compiler is expecting you to put single Guids in the brackets, not a list of Guids. Here is what you need to do:

```
List<Guid> subPageGuids = (from x in subPages select x.Id).ToList();
```